# How to handle exceptions in games

Tags: java

I'm programming a game that has user interaction through the console. The user would enter a command followed by a space and then the parameters of said command. Example:

```
 move-piece 5-right
```

The command is "move-piece" and the parameters are "5-right" (5 spots to the right). I have a method that checks if the command and parameters were entered in the correct format. The method then calls a move method with the parameters that moves the piece on the board. An example of an exception case could be that the game is already over, in which case the user is not allowed to move any pieces. Another exception case is moving the piece outside the board. I always read about how using exceptions for control flow is bad, but I don't really understand what that means.

```
if (gameOver){
  throw new CustomGameException("you cannot move any pieces, because the game is over.");
}
```

Is the above considered controlling the flow with exceptions? Of course this isn't the only situation in which a game rule is broken. I have many more if statements that check for edge cases, but I'm not sure if that's a good thing or not. If the above is considered bad practice, how else should I handle such cases? I want to be able to print out a unique message for each edge case to inform the user about his/her mistake. I should note that this is for a school project and we are not allowed to have any System.out.print in our main code. The output gets printed to the user in the main method.

EDIT for clarity:
 We are not allowed to have print methods within our code. Output is done in the main method. The suggested solution given to us by our teacher also used exceptions to handle such cases. An example of such usage in the solution is when the user attempts to roll a die twice in a row (which is not allowed according to the game rules). My teacher threw an exception in the roll method for such a scenario. The teacher also says that we are not supposed to use exceptions to control the flow, which is why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Bad user input is not *exceptional*, it is *expected*. So don't use an exception.

Comment: So what is considered exceptional in a game?

Comment: A corrupted save file, for example. You *expect* it to be okay. Under *exceptional* circumstances it may not be.

Comment: You can easily handle such case with a basic print method. Why do you need to raise an Exception?

Comment: @Ctorres We are not allowed to have print methods within our code. Output is done in the main method. The suggested solution given to us by our teacher also used exceptions to handle such cases. An example of such usage in the solution is when the user attempts to roll a die twice in a row (which is not allowed according to the game rules). My teacher threw an exception in the roll method for such a scenario. The teacher also says that we are not supposed to use exceptions to control the flow, which is why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: "I always read about how using exceptions for control flow is bad, but I don't really understand what that means."  It means that the author of such claims does not understand himself that "control flow" is the ***very reason*** why exceptions were invented in the first place.

Comment: The statement may not be precise, true. But I think it is fairly clear what he meant. I.e. do not use exceptions for non-exceptional cases. Exceptions are slow and should only rarely be triggered. Do not provoke an exception if you can detect it beforehand (with a simple `if` for example). For example, do not access an invalid array index and catch the exception. Instead, use an `if` to check the index beforehand.

Comment: @Zabuza space too small here to debunk.  Exceptions are slow only if you let them be.  Java currently has ways to avoid it.  And checking failure conditions twice (which is what happens if you're forcing people to do the checking explicitly upfront and then the same check is going to be performed a second time just for the method to know it won't need to throw) is by definition always going to be slower than checking once.

Comment: @RakoonBerry It seems like it's just a training about using exceptions, about throwing and handling it... Just keep in mind that an exception is probably too much in your case, and you'd do otherwise in a real case scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't take the statement about not using exceptions for control flow too literally. There are many cases where exceptions work just fine.

One is where it's hard (or outside the responsibility) for the code that knows how to handle the error to detect whether the error will occur or not. Your situation might be an example of this: You want to handle all user interaction in the main method, but all kinds of things at various depth into your code can invalidate a command. So throw an exception and be done with it. Don't worry about the performance of something that will happen at most once every time a user enters some text.

Another reason to use exceptions would be where there are natural race conditions in checking if an operation might succeed or not. e.g. you want to create a file, but a common occurrence is that a file with the same name might already exist or you might be out of disk space or something similar. In that case it's no use to check if the operation will succeed as it might still fail later when you do the operation. Just try to do it and catch the right exceptions.

Advice on the form "never use X" is common in programming and almost never worthy of the zeal with witch it is presented.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does seem easier for me to do that. I have many exceptions which are thrown through out my code. In my main method, I have a try-catch that prints the custom error message if an exception is caught.